# iOS 7 UIBarButtonItem with accessibility

Tags: ios, accessibility, uibarbuttonitem

Im trying to give my barbuttonitem in the navigationBar a value that the VoiceOver can read, instead of reading the imgname.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
self.barBtnAbout.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"about", nil);
self.barBtnAbout.accessibilityHint = NSLocalizedString(@"about", nil);
```

Any bright ideas?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this using the following:

```
UIView *view = (UIView*)self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
[view setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
[view setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"about", @"")];
[view setAccessibilityHint:NSLocalizedString(@"about", @"")];
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to setup basic accessibility for a UIBarButtonItem is like this:

```
myBarButtonItem.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
myBarButtonItem.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"a short description",@"")];
myBarButtonItem.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
```

Comment: What if I want to no traits? I want Voice Over to read only the label. I tried setting the trait to  UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText, but it keeps saying button.